# Driver's logbook app for Android (FOSS)

Tags: android, open-source, car, journal

I'm looking for a free and libre Android app to use as driver's logbook. Even a simple manual one would do for starters – but data must be stored locally, not in the cloud.

**Must-haves:**

- Android
- free and libre
- sufficient details for tax purposes (i.e. logs mileage status at start, has fields for purpose, location etc)
- can export to a "generic" format (PDF, CSV, …)
- all data is stored on-device (storing to a self-hosted server e.g. Nextcloud is acceptable)

**Much appreciated:**

- uses metric units (kilometers; of course no problem if it *can* use imperial miles *as well*)
- fills start/end via GPS/network-location
- uses Nominatim to convert coordinates to location names
- allows for fuel logs as well

**Nice-to-Haves:**

- OBDII support for additional details
- lets me mark frequent locations¹/purposes to select from (so I'd not have to enter the same data over and again)
- asks me whether to start/stop a journey when a connection to OBDII/the-car is established/lost (so I cannot forget to "stamp in/out")

**No-Gos:**

- mandatory cloud storage
- bound to a service requiring registration
- requirement to connect it with the car's "entertainment system" (or any other car systems apart from ODBII); *optional* connections are acceptable as long as they are OFF by default and it's guaranteed they stay off unless I explicitly tell the app otherwise
- ATS (Ad and Tracking Services / libraries)

Ideally, the app and its source are available from a publicly reachable forge (like Codeberg.org, GitLab, Github – a self-hosted Gitea/Forgejo of course is fine, too). My searches at F-Droid.org as well as at the mentioned forges came up empty so far, but I might have used the wrong search terms.

PS: Should there be any developers here considering writing such an app, I'd also volunteer as tester (though my trips are not that frequent).

---

¹ <sub>Nominatim is nice, but sometimes you'd want the name of the person/company instead of the street address</sub>